# Wrong TActionMainMenuBar icon bar width in HDPI in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, vcl

If I use a higher DPI setting in Windows then the recommended one (200% instead of 150%), the icon bar width and the check mark size of the `TActionMainMenuBar` submenus not scale. The menu item captions overlap with the icons. Is there any system setting to resolve this problem without to modify the VCL source?